# How to access the meta attributes of a superclass in Python?

Tags: python, django

I have some code like this for [Django-Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
class SpecializedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = MyCustomAuthentication()

class TestResource(SpecializedResource):
    class Meta:
        # the following style works:
        authentication = SpecializedResource.authentication
        # but the following style does not:
        super(TestResource, meta).authentication
```

I would like to know what would be the right method of accessing meta attributes of the superclass without hard-coding the name of the superclass.

Comment: In the snippet you provided the name of a superclass is not hard-coded - `super()` takes the name of a *current* class.

Comment: And as the comment says, it does not work :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example it seems that you are trying to override the attribute of the meta of the super class. Why not use meta inheritance?

```
class MyCustomAuthentication(Authentication):
    pass

class SpecializedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = MyCustomAuthentication()

class TestResource(SpecializedResource):
    class Meta(SpecializedResource.Meta):
        # just inheriting from parent meta
        pass
    print Meta.authentication
```

Output:

```
<__main__.MyCustomAuthentication object at 0x6160d10>
```

so that the `TestResource`'s `meta` are inheriting from parent meta (here the authentication attribute).

**Finally answering the question:**

If you really want to access it (for example to append stuff to a parent list and so on), you can use your example:

```
class TestResource(SpecializedResource):
    class Meta(SpecializedResource.Meta):
        authentication = SpecializedResource.Meta.authentication # works (but hardcoding)
```

or without **hard coding** the **super** class:

```
class TestResource(SpecializedResource):
    class Meta(SpecializedResource.Meta):
        authentication = TestResource.Meta.authentication # works (because of the inheritance)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for without knowing it. Thank you! Actually, no need of declaring authentication in TestResource is necessary. When meta-inheritance works, it simply works.